# Getting OpenStack Server's Tags

Tags: java, openstack-nova, jclouds

I'm using jclouds Java SDK, i search in the documentation and in the jclouds examples for how to get the tags of a Nova server, but i didn't find any mention of it. i found some other function to get the instance name, instance metadata and so on in the following code

```
NovaApi novaApi = computeServiceContext.unwrapApi(NovaApi.class);
String region = novaApi.getConfiguredRegions().iterator().next();
ServerApi serverApi = novaApi.getServerApi(region);
Server instance = serverApi.get(TEMP_SERVERNAME);
```

in the variable `instance` i can get information about the instance such as metadata for example, but not the tags.
my question is this [OpenStack API](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#list-tags) implemented in the jclouds SDKs? if yes how can i call it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That API call is not yet implemented in the jclouds Server API. However, it should be pretty easy and straightforward to add that method. Would you be willing to contribute to the project and add it? I would be more than happy to help you get that done!

Comment: thanks for the offer, I will try it out, but the thing is that I still don't have the testing environment. I will keep you posted if I got everything working

Comment: I have test environment for swift and zaqar, but still I need to have nova environment for testing